# I2C not working in PIC18F46K22 for DS3231

Tags: pic, mplab, xc8

I'm using PIC18F46K22 to display the time from DS3231 rtc device via I2C. I'm facing issue while setting the acknowledgement (ACKEN). I'm feeling something wrong in my configuration especially in Pin Configuration and setting the baud rate with SSP1ADD.

I'm using 20MHz and my DS3231 is supports for 400kHz.

While setting the acknowledgement(ACKEN), program getting hang, I mean, it is not able to set it not coming out from the step.

Please help me to fix the issue, please find the attached code.

Comment: Please edit your main post with code formatted, is difficult to read, also you can attach schematics in your main post

Comment: How can I upload my code here? since, am new to this site.

Comment: you can copy paste the code directly in to your post , select it then click on the '{ }' button.

Comment: ...you'll need to click 'edit' on your main post first

Comment: I'm struggling find to edit my post, am not able to find edit option so, I published new post with all the code.

Comment: I can't find your new post - has it been deleted?

Comment: new question posted with heading - I2C not working in PIC18F46K22 using DS3231-